# Homotopy for the complement when slightly thickening a subspace of $ℝ^n$

Tags: homotopy-theory

For a given subspace $X \subset ℝ^n$ there is a homotopy equivalence $X \times \{0\} \simeq X \times I$ (subspaces of $ℝ^{n+1}$), where $I$ is the unit interval. However, the complements in $ℝ^{n+1}$ are not necessarily homotopic.

The complements should be homotopic for nice spaces $X$, in particular when $X$ is closed (hopefully). Unfortunately I fail to find a reference for this, could someone please point me in the right direction?

---

Example where the complements differ:

Let $N = ℝ \setminus (\{\frac{1}{2^n}|n\in \mathbb{N}\}\cup \{0\}$) then
$\pi_1(ℝ^2 \setminus (N\times 0))$ is larger than
$\pi_1(ℝ^2 \setminus (N\times I))$ because the former contains
loops with infinitely many circles, the later doesn't.

---

This is a special case of [a much broader question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/213698/complement-of-deformation-retract) asked a year
ago. The older question is wrong (does not sufficiently restrict the class of allowed sets $X$) and has
no (to me) useful answer.

Comment: I really don't understand your question nor your example: you make use of $X\times 0$ and $X\times I$ in a way that it is not standard (and I don't understand). Also, what do you mean exactly by homotopy between spaces? homotopy is usually defined between maps. Could you please be more precise?

Comment: I think he means homotopy equivalent.

Comment: Yes exactly, sorry I was unclear about that. I was referring to homotopy equivalence.